# How to resolve the “ColorspaceColorProfileMismatch 'icc'” conflict when creating an image?

Tags: php, imagick

Good day, dear $user!

There is a source file in "in.png" PNG format with sRGB scheme.
Must be converted to "TIFF" with CMYK scheme and FOGRA27 profile.

When the script is run, the exception "***ColorspaceColorProfileMismatch` icc '@error/profile.c/ProfileImage/866*** "

What's my mistake?

```
$inFile = in.png 
$outFile = out.tiff

$base = new Imagick($inFile);
$base->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_CMYK);
$base->mergeImageLayers( Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_MERGE);
$base->profileImage('icc', Storage::disk('local')->url('icc_profile/forga27.icc'));
$base->setImageUnits(1);
$base->setImageResolution(127,127);
$base->setCompression(11);
$base->setImageFormat("tiff");
$base->writeImage($outFile);
$base->destroy();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Storage::disk ('local')->get('icc_profile/fogra27.icc') I passed url (Storage::disk('local')->url('icc_profile/forga27.icc'))

Thank.